# Visual Studio - ExcludeFromCodeCoverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and C# and am doing unit tests and viewing code coverage.  There are some classes I want to exclude from the code coverage, so I read that you can use the

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]

Attribute.  The only problem is it causes a red line underneath it and it has the dreaded

Error   16  The type or namespace name 'ExcludeFromCodeCoverage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?  I even have a 'using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;' line, and the right click->resolve does not present itself with any fixes.

Comment: What framework are you using? the attribute is only available in .net 4 as far as I can see -> [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a Test based on Shaun's comment, and to be more explicit about the possible solution:

I get a red line under that attribute when my "Target framework" in the project properties page is set to a version less than 4, such as 3.5.  Changing the Target framework to version 4 or version 4 client profile, fixed the issue and allowed the attribute to resolve.